# How to update value in nested json Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have following JSON stored in "Info" column

```json
{
  "customConfig": {
    "isCustomGoods": 1
  },
  "new_addfields": {
    "data": [
      {
        "val": {
          "items": [
            {
              "Code": "calorie",
              "Value": "365.76"
            },
            {
              "Code": "protein",
              "Value": "29.02"
            },
            {
              "Code": "fat",
              "Value": "23.55"
            },
            {
              "Code": "carbohydrate",
              "Value": "6.02"
            },
            {
              "Code": "spirit",
              "Value": "1.95"
            }
          ],
          "storageConditions": "",
          "outQuantity": "100"
        },
        "parameterType": "Nutrition",
        "name": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
        "label": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "b4589168-5235-4ec5-bcc7-07d4431d14d6_Для ресторанов",
        "val": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to update value of nested json

```json
{
  "name": "b4589168-5235-4ec5-bcc7-07d4431d14d6_Для ресторанов",
  "val": "true"
}
```

and set "val"to "Yes" str so the result should be like

```json
{
  "name": "b4589168-5235-4ec5-bcc7-07d4431d14d6_Для ресторанов",
  "val": "Yes"
}
```

How can i do that ? Assuming that i need to update this value in json for many records in database

Comment: Whether your JSON structure is fixed or it can be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Considering you have a constant JSON Structure and a primary key in your table.** Idea is to get the exact path of element `val` having value `true` (which can be at any index in the array) then replace it with desired value. So you can write your query like below:

```sql
with cte as (
select 
  id, 
  ('{new_addfields,data,'||index-1||',val}')::text[] as json_path
from 
  test, 
  jsonb_array_elements(info->'new_addfields'->'data') 
  with ordinality arr(vals,index) 
where 
  arr.vals->>'val' ilike 'true'
  )

 update test 
 set info = jsonb_set(info,cte.json_path,'"Yes"',false) 
 from cte 
 where test.id=cte.id;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aa3f21b5ea1acce28bdbcd008ccaf2f7)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `jsonb_set()` which is available from Postgres 9.5+

From [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html):

```sql
jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])
```

Query to update the nested object:

```sql
UPDATE temp t
SET info = jsonb_set(t.info,'{new_addfields,data,1,val}', jsonb '"Yes"')
where id = 1;
```

It can also be used in select query:

```sql
SELECT 
  jsonb_set(t.info,'{new_addfields,data,1,val}', jsonb '"Yes"')
FROM temp t
LIMIT 1;
```