# How to update a specific value of a object present in array of object within Postgres JSON Field

Tags: python, sql, json, django, postgresql

Here is my JSON field value. which is stored in the PostgreSQL table. I want to search and update the specific `user_name` in the `user` key

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Meet",
            "user_weight": 0.07447325861051013
        },
        {
            "user_name": "L.b.vasoya",
            "user_weight": 0.056163873153859706
        }
    ],
    "address": [
        {
            "address_name": "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

whose name is `Devang`
to `Dev` using Django **JSONField**
for example

```
 "user": [
        {
            "user_name": "Dev",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
....
```

I have tried the **RAWQuery** for the find. This is the query.

```
select json_field->user from user_table where json_field @> '{"user": [{"user_name": "Devang"}]}';
```

It will return like this

```
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Meet",
            "user_weight": 0.07447325861051013
        },
        {
            "user_name": "L.b.vasoya",
            "user_weight": 0.056163873153859706
        }
]
```

I have also tried *JSON_SET* to update the user_name but *JSON_SET* only accepts. It will update the upper level, not a nesting level

Comment: Please add some more explanation in your question. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64569848/7772483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JSONB_SET`is a bit tricky in case of nested element updation. If you want to set the value of nested element first you need to get the exact path  of element to be updated. Please try below query:

```sql
with cte as (
  select  id,  ('{user,'||index-1||',user_name}')::text[] as json_path
  from user_table, jsonb_array_elements(json_field->'user') 
  with ordinality arr(vals,index) where arr.vals->>'user_name' ='Devang' --put the value to be replaced
  )
 update user_table 
set json_field = jsonb_set(json_field,cte.json_path,'"Dev"',false) --put the new value in '""' here
 from cte where user_table.id=cte.id;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=eceb064da0504603caf9d0aa0aa187fa)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have another issue can please check it once. Here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8a2acd961ab6e0e2e568f932268564cb in the second record has two **Devang** user_name it will update only once what should I do to change all match user_name